# How to change theme tabs to be more lighter in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the theme color extention (light color) and don't like the theme tab dark colors:

[image]

I would like to have something more lighter tabs like this:

[image]

How can I change it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the cause of the colorized tags.

It happend because of a `Productivity Power Tools` extension. All I need to do is to go to: Tool -> Opthions -> Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> uncheck the checkbox `Color tabs by project`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check these out:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05